# Converting a filter in JOIN clause to WHERE clause

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, left-join, where-clause, amazon-athena

I have a query where there is a filter condition added in JOIN clause. I have to move that condition to WHERE clause. is it possible?

Code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ut.vehicle_id, DATE(ut.DATE) Date, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ut.vehicle_id ORDER BY DATE(UT.DATE)) RN
FROM 
    awsdatacatalog.waves.unlimited_wash_transaction ut
LEFT JOIN 
    awsdatacatalog.waves.wash_invoice WI ON WI.invoice_id = ut.invoice_id
LEFT JOIN 
    awsdatacatalog.waves.unlimited_customer uc ON UC.vehicle_id = UT.vehicle_id
                                               AND start_date BETWEEN DATE('2021-05-01') AND DATE('2021-05-30')
WHERE 
    DATE(UT.date) BETWEEN DATE('2021-05-01') AND Date('2021-05-31') 
    AND (ut.Status IN ('RESIGNUP', 'RECURRING')) 
    AND UC.vehicle_id IS NULL
    AND WI.Status IN ('Completed', 'PartiallyRefunded') 
    AND (ut.Is_Refunded IS NULL OR CAST(ut.Is_Refunded AS INTEGER) = 0)
ORDER B Y
    ut.vehicle_id
```

I want to move the condition :

```
start_date BETWEEN Date('2021-05-01') AND Date('2021-05-30')
```

to the `WHERE` clause but if I do that I get incorrect results.

Please help me.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` condition is the criteria to match rows between two sources. `WHERE` condition is to filter result dataset. So they have different meaning and purpose and you need to clarify why do you want to move this condition to `where` and what do you want to achieve.

Comment: "it gives incorrect result" - then it's the wrong thing to do and you should put it back the way it was. It's definitely different logic, what makes you think you need to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to move it? Just to make it look prettier?

Answer (score 0):

Moving join condition from an outer (left/right) join to where clause is a bad idea. Let me explain why.

Say, we have two tables, employees and their cars

Employees
| emp_id | name |
|--------|------|
| 1 | Carl |
| 2 | Donald |
| 3 | Paula |

Cars
| emp_id | car |
|--------|----|
| 1 | Opel |
|3 | BMW |

Now let's imagine we don't like BMWs so left join those table according to our taste

```
select e.name, c.car
  from employees e
  LEFT join cars.c
    on e.emp_id = c.emp_id
   AND c.car <> 'BMW'
```

The query will first filter out cars table to remove the "BMW" line and will perform outer join. "Left join" means "take all the lines from first table join second table to it and fill absent lines with nulls".

So, the result will be like that

| name | car |
| --- | --- |
| Carl | Opel |
| Donald | null |
| Paula | null |

Note that Donald has null because he hasn't any car at all and Paula has BMW but it was filtered out BEFORE join took place.

Now, when filter has been moved to the WHERE part

```
select e.name, c.car
  from employees e
  LEFT join cars.c
    on e.emp_id = c.emp_id
 WHERE c.car <> 'BMW'
```

The DB will now join tables first (see step1 table below) and will apply filter afterwards (see step2 table below).

Step1 - at this step only left join was performed

| name | car |
| --- | --- |
| Carl | Opel |
| Donald | null |
| Paula | BMW |

Step2 - This is the end result after filter "car <> 'BMW' " has been applied

| name | car |
| --- | --- |
| Carl | Opel |
| Donald | null |

What's missing?

I don't see why you needed to move that condition from join to the where clause, but if you insist, you'll have to not only filter dates but keep all the lines where start_date is null in order to get same results.

So, it'll be something of that kind

```
(start_date is null or start_date BETWEEN Date('2021-05-01') AND Date('2021-05-30'))
```

Comment: Damn, miss that. Thanks @GordonLinoff !